# How to add desktop platform module to existing libGDX project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, module, libgdx, desktop

I have created a libGDX project in Android Studio. When I first created the project, I only selected the "Android" subproject.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Now, I have changed my mind and want to add a desktop platform module to my libGDX project in order to run the "Tools" extension. There doesn't seem to be another question asking this on *stackoverflow*, and that is why I am asking it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know **Project Name** and **package** of your already generated libgdx project.

Generate another project with above details at some other place then copy the desktop folder in your old project.

Now you've to add that module in your project.

- Add your desktop module in `settings.gradle` file
- Add desktop configuration in your project `build.gradle` file

Done, Sync your project dependency.

**EDIT**

Content inside settings.gradle file should be like this :

```
include  'android', 'core', 'desktop'
```

Add below code in your project level `build.gradle` file

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}
```

Comment: You said to copy the desktop folder in your old project. By that, you mean copying just the desktop folder from the newly generated blank project to the original project? Also, where should I paste the desktop folder to? Should I paste it to the project tab? Also, is it possible if you could paste the code for the new settings.gradle and build.gradle files? Thanks!

Comment: Yes just the desktop folder. Paste in your project folder where you've core and android folder(use window file explore), check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be what you are looking for but what I would do is generate another LibGDX project with the Project Setup app with desktop checked and copy-paste all my code into this new project, optionally, if you want the new project to have the same name rename previous as "previous-backup"
Remember to add a desktop configuration, here's a example from one of my projects:
[image: what's in red is just my project specific paths]